# Default player doesn't play *some* .ogg files

Tags: media-player

I have ripped a number of CD's with Rhythmbox on Ubuntu.

I've noticed not all files play.

- Some .ogg files do play on my Android Galaxy S6
- Some .ogg files do not play ...

I have no idea what can be the problem. I don't see any difference in the properties between the files that play and those that don't.

Could you help me troubleshoot this?

**Edit:** The plot thickens, I've converted some files to MP3 and ... they still don't play.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing them with VLC, [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc) is the link for the Google play store.